# error when save .xlsm --> .xltm

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel book in .xlsm format (it contains code) and, with this extension, it does not give me any type of error. On the other hand, saving as .xltm gives me the following error message:

"This workbook contains external data. Do you want Microsoft Excel to clear the data before saving the template, and then automatically refresh the data whenever the template is opened? "

The strange thing is that I have reviewed the entire book and there are no external links: I have reviewed (in all book sheets): i) formulas, ii) data connections, iii) conditional formats, iv) names. It haven't pivot tables.

I did the .xlsm in Excel 2010 and I save it as .xltm in Excel 2010 and in Excel 2016. In both cases I have the same problem. I tried in Windows 7 and Windows 10 too.

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The book has 3 sheets. When I delete one of them (and only this one) the problem disappears:Then, I focus on this sheet and I delete row by row, element by element (button of macro, graph...) and always the problem persists. Even I delete the whole rows and objects and the problem persists. Only when I delete completely the sheet, the problem desappears.... Could be a hidden property of this specific sheet??

Answer (score 1):

Is there any macros in the VB code for the page you are deleting? If so, check the VBA code for any external links, etc. as these may be causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

An xltm is a template for a spreadsheet, not a spreadsheet. All it contains is formatting for a specific type of spreadsheet you can use as a start. When I opem up excel, it gives me a number of templates I can base a new spreadsheet on:

[image: Excel 2016 startup/New screen]

As a template is not expected to have any actual data in it (e.g. a CV template would not come pre-loaded with details of my career) it's just telling you that all t he data you have in the currently loaded spreadsheet will not get saved.

Comment: Sorry, I think you don't give my point. We work with tones of templates with a lot of formulas and even code and this is the first time that I get this error. But thanks for your comment.